# Java says not equal while they are

Tags: java, unit-testing, assert

Java says that the following are not equal while they are:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<[[(7,UP), (2,RIGHT)], [(4,DOWN), (11,MIDDLE)], 
[(9,RIGHT), (1,UP)]]>
 but was:<[[(2,RIGHT), (7,UP)], [(11,MIDDLE), (4,DOWN)], [(1,UP), (9,RIGHT)]]>
```

(where each is a HashSet and each subset is another HashSet)

Comment: It would be very nice of you, if you could show classes that you're using.

Comment: The classes are a huge mess. I am interested in knowing what can cause such an error

Comment: Did you implement `equals` method for those classes as well?

Comment: Did you implement the equals and hashCode method for the classes of the elements that you put in a HashSet

Comment: Are you sure the `assertEquals()` you are using doesn't care about element ordering?

Comment: @fge the `equals` of the `HashSet` does not care for the ordering and `assertEquals` just calls that

Comment: @B.J.Smegma except that many unit test frameworks have dedicated `assertEquals()` for `Collection`s -- and `Set`s are `Collection`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No code is shown, so these are only guesses.

First, as mentioned, the elements of your `Set`s don't implement `.equals()`/`.hashCode()`.

Second, you use `assertEquals()` on `Collection`s: many test frameworks (TestNG for instance), when faced with `Collection`s as arguments, will succeed if and only if the two collections have the same elements *in the same order*. Use another method, such as, for instance, `assertEqualsNoOrder-)` -- but here this is complicated by the fact that you have embedded `Collection`s. Or just use `assertTrue(coll1.equals(coll2))`.

Comment: For Hashcode I always return 1. I was told when I asked a similar question once that hashCode under some circumstances does not matter

Comment: Bad idea, because this is as suboptimal a hashcode you can make (although legal). If you use sets, you should have a hashCode() method with a decent distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the problem is that the equals() or hashCode() method of the type represented by (7,UP), etc., does not behave the way you expect.